# Android. nativescript-plugin-firebase. How to fix auth error?

Tags: javascript, android, plugins, firebase, nativescript

I use this plugin in my app:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase

But On my real device in 3g network I have this error: **auth/network-request-failed Thrown if a network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.**

How to fix it??

P.S. I write Javascript code, not Typescript..

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is more likely firebase related then NativeScript code related one.Try the following solution:

- Go to **console.firebase.google.com/project/MY_APP_NAME**
- Open **Authentication** >> **Set Up Sign-in Method** >> **Add Domain**
- Add your domain

Comment: What is a domain? The default domain *..firebaseapp.com is added. Other domains I have not. This is not the web, it's an android app ..